# How to sort a list within hashmap by elements of the same key

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to make a hash map which would include the name of the object(key), and a list of all the objects with that name. Something like this:

```
"bob" = obj1, obj2

"Mark" = obj3
```

I have created a sort method in order to try and accomplish this but I can't make it work:

```
public class sorter {

    public static Object obj = new Object("mark");
    public static Object obj1 = new Object("bob");
    public static Object obj2 = new Object("mark");
    public static Object obj3 = new Object("mark");

    public static List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

    private static Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();

    public static List<Object> tempList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public static String key;
    public static int values;

    public static void sort(List<Object> objects) {

        for(int i = 0; i<objects.size(); i++) {

            key = objects.get(i).getName();
            if(map.containsKey(key)) {
                map.get(key).add(objects.get(i));
            }
            else {
                tempList.add(objects.get(i));
                map.put(key, tempList);
            }
            //reset
            //key = null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        objects.add(obj);
        //objects.add(obj1);
        //objects.add(obj2);
        //objects.add(obj3);
        sort(objects);
        System.out.println(map.get("mark"));
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: `tempList` should be declared/created in the loop (in the `else` block)

Comment: This isn't sorting (otherwise known as ordering in programming) , it's grouping

Comment: **Guava Multimap** is what you need: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are severals issues with your code at the moment. let's go through them:

1. You're not sorting, you're grouping.
2. calling a class `sorter` is not a meaningful name and doesn't follow the java naming convention.
3. `new Object("mark");` will not compile as there is only one constructor for the `Object` class and that is the default constructor, taking no parameters.
4. `objects.get(i).getName();` will not compile as there is no `getName` method in the object class.
5. try to avoid using the `Object` class as much as possible and in this case, it makes more sense to create a `Person` class.

Example:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    // ... some additional fields
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person1{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then your `Sorter` class becomes:

```
class Grouping {

    public static Person obj = new Person("mark");
    public static Person obj1 = new Person("bob");
    public static Person obj2 = new Person("mark");
    public static Person obj3 = new Person("mark");

    public static List<Person> objects = new ArrayList<>();

    private static Map<String, List<Person>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void groupByName(List<Person> objects) {
       map = objects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName));
       // group by the person name
    }


    public static void main(String[]args) {
        objects.add(obj);
        objects.add(obj1);
        objects.add(obj2);
        objects.add(obj3);
        groupByName(objects);
        System.out.println(map.get("mark"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming OP doesn't use his own `Object` class with one String property called `name`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java8 streams like below :

```
    public static void sort(List<Object> objects) {
       map =objects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy((o) -> o.getName()));
    }
```